# Apps Script throws an error when passing a folder id string into a custom function which calls DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getDateCreated();

Tags: google-apps-script

This code will throw this error:

> Exception: Invalid argument: id (line 2, file "Code")

at the top of the editor window in red, and still log the date file was created. What is going on here?

```
function getFolderData(id){
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);     
  return folder.getDateCreated();
}
Logger.log(getFolderData('1DsSOQD52eWPnCPyuQL09KhyDpdwdJ1jl'));
```

and this code runs successfully

```
function getFolderData(){
  let id = '1DsSOQD52eWPnCPyuQL09KhyDpdwdJ1jl';
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);     
  Logger.log(folder.getDateCreated());
}
getFolderData();
```

I've checked to make sure input is type string

```
function getFolderData(id){
 return 'typeof SourceID: ' + typeof id;
}
Logger.log(getFolderData('1DsSOQD52eWPnCPyuQL09KhyDpdwdJ1jl'));
```

which logs "[20-11-30 21:36:03:200 EST] typeof SourceID: string
" which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

The issue with your approach is that you are trying to execute `getFolderData(id)` via the script editor but this function can not be ran as a **standalone** function because **it requires an argument** and that is `id`.

This part of your code:

`Logger.log(getFolderData('1DsSOQD52eWPnCPyuQL09KhyDpdwdJ1jl'));`

is correct, but it is **outside** of every function and therefore it is a global execution. It will be executed regardless of the function you decide to run.

The issue though remains the same, you are trying to execute a function from the script editor that requires an argument.

### Solution:

Create a new function, name it however you like and call `getFolderData` from **within** this function:

```
function runMe(){
  Logger.log(getFolderData('1DsSOQD52eWPnCPyuQL09KhyDpdwdJ1jl'));
}

function getFolderData(id){
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);     
  return folder.getDateCreated();
}
```

Make sure you have selected the `runMe` function and execute it:

[image]

Please don't forget to remove `Logger.log(getFolderData('1DsSOQD52eWPnCPyuQL09KhyDpdwdJ1jl'));` that is outside of every function and only use it within this newly created `runMe` function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I see where the error is now.